# do-release-upgrade command failing

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I'm getting an error in upgrading my ubuntu from 14.04 to newer versions, I probably deleted something while clearing up the space for new installation, hence i'm getting the following error:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/do-release-upgrade: No such file or directory
```

Can someone tell me how to resolve this and continue with upgrade instructions?

Comment: That command is provided by the package `ubuntu-release-upgrader-core`. Do you have that package installed?

Answer (score 3):

Upgrading from 14.04 may yield some unresolvable errors as it left general support almost two years ago. That said, you *may* be able to upgrade by installing the `update-manager-core` package … assuming it's still available. Here's how:

1. Back up your system
2. Update apt:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
3. Install the `update-manager-core` package:

   ```
   sudo apt install update-manager-core
   ```
4. Upgrade the OS to 16.04, which loses general support in six weeks:

   ```
   sudo do-release-upgrade
   ```

A faster, less error-riddled way would be to reinstall the OS from scratch. A lot has changed since 14.04, so starting with a fresh 20.04 (or newer) installation would save a lot of time, bandwidth, and hassle. Just be sure to make a decent backup of your important files beforehand.

Comment: Note that this will not work if you wait for too long. I am currently facing an issue with 22.10, which reached its end of life in July 2023. The `do-release-upgrade` will fail (but not with an error) requesting the user to first do an update of the current system. However, an update will fail if the repository no longer has a release file (happens when end of life is reached).